# Unknown class PFImageView in Interface Builder file

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com and I have a ViewController with inside a TableView ...

The cell of TableView is personalized and contains inside an ImageView with PFImageView class.

When do I run it all works, show me the photos regularly but Xcode 5 shows me this error message

PFImageView Unknown class in Interface Builder file.

How come I get this error? Where am I doing wrong

Below I show the implementation of the PFImageView in the table view.

P.S. PFImageView and 'has also been added to the @ property of CustomTableViewCell.h

```
-(FFCellFindUser *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellFindUser";
    FFCellFindUser *cell = [self.FFTableViewFindUser dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[FFCellFindUser alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    PFObject *TempObject = [self.FFTotalUser objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.FFLabelCell_NomeCognome.text = [TempObject objectForKey:FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME];


    PFFile *imageFile = [TempObject objectForKey:FF_USER_FOTOPROFILO];
    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        cell.FFIMGCell_FotoProfilo.image =[UIImage imageWithData:data];  }];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Remove " if (!cell) {
        cell = [[FFCellFindUser alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }" and show us a screen from IB of the cell prototype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PFImage has a call to use instead of using getData.

Assuming you get your cell loaded correctly from my comment.

http://blog.parse.com/2012/07/11/loading-remote-images-stored-on-parse/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that changing the class for the custom UITableViewCell cell in PFTableViewCell has solved the problem ... In this way, the compiler has recognized the PFImageView.

Comment: Can you explain this one?  My table cell is already of type PFTableViewCell and I still get unknown class PFImageView